# Nock not catch post requests using chai-http and mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, nock, chai-http

I'm creating a web app that connects with an API in order to do a login and some stuff, currently I'm trying to test a `/authenticate` route on my app using `chai`, `chai-http` and `nock`.

```
var chai = require('chai');        
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var nock = require('nock');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/authenticate', function() {
var agent = chai.request.agent('http://localhost:3000');

  afterEach(function() {
    agent.close();         
    nock.cleanAll();       
  });

  describe('User authorized', function() {
    it('redirects to /dashboard', function() {
      // I'm trying to mock the response here but is not working.
      nock('http://the.api.com:8080')
      .post('/v1/authenticate')
      .reply(201, {
        'authorized': true,
        'jwt': 'thejwtasdf'
      });
      agent
      .post('/authenticate')
      .send({ email: 'test@gmail.com', password: 'TheAmazingPass' })
      .then(function(res) {
        expect(res).to.redirectTo('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
        expect(res.text).to.match(/Dashboard/);
      })
      .catch(function(e) { console.log(e);  });
    });
  });
});
```

The test pass but I got this caught error, according to this, the page is not redirected because the call is not caught by nock and it is directly sent to the API:

```
{ AssertionError: expected redirect with 30X status code but got 200
  at Proxy.<anonymous>
  ... rest of the error omitted.
```

But when I use a real and valid email and password this test pass with no caught error:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var nock = require('nock');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/authenticate', function() {
  var agent = chai.request.agent('http://localhost:3000')

  afterEach(function() {
    agent.close();
    nock.cleanAll();
  });

  describe('User authorized', function() {
    it('redirects to /dashboard', function() {
      agent
      .post('/authenticate')
      .send({ email: 'realemail@gmail.com', password: 'RealPass'  })
      .then(function(res) {
        expect(res).to.redirectTo('http://localhost:3000/dashboard');
        expect(res.text).to.match(/Dashboard/);
      })
      .catch(function(e) { console.log(e);  });
    });
  });
});
```

With this code the test passes, Am I missing something with nock?

=== EDIT ===

This is the code that I'm trying to test:

This is my login router (flashMessages is a custom middleware that helps with flash messages).

```
var loginService = require('../services/login');
var flashMessages = require('../utils/flash_messages').flashMessages;
var router = require('express').Router();

// check if user is logged in
var sessionChecker = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.auth && req.cookies.user_sid) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

router.get('/', sessionChecker, flashMessages, function(req, res, next){
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'Welcome',
    errors: res.locals.flash.errors,
    typeError: res.locals.flash.errorType,
  });
});

router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res, next){
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email format').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.getValidationResult().then(function(result){
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
      loginService.authenticate(req.body).then(function(result){
        if (result.authorized){
          // success
          req.session.auth = result;
          req.session.auth.user = loginService.currentUser(result.jwt)
          res.redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
          // user not found error
          req.session.flash = {
            errors: [{msg: result.msg}],
            errorType: 'anotherError'
          };
          res.redirect('/');
        }
      }).catch(function(e){
        // server errors
        req.session.flash = {
          errors: [e],
          errorType: 'anotherError'
        };
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    } else {
      //validation errors
      req.session.flash = {
        errors: result.array(),
        errorType: 'validationError'
      };
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The login router uses a loginService, this is the part that works with the login:

```
var httpReq = require('../utils/http_requests');

module.exports.authenticate = function(params){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    httpReq.callToAPI(params, {
      path: '/v1/authenticate',
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(function(authorization) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(authorization));
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.currentUser = function(shaCode){
  return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(shaCode.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString());
};
```

And finally I have a utils for http requests:

```
var http = require('http');

function createOptions(options) {
  headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Connection': 'close'
  };
  if (options.jwt) { headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + options.jwt; }
  return {
    hostname: 'the.api.com',
    port: 8080,
    path: options.path,
    method: options.method,
    headers: headers
  };
};

module.exports.callToAPI = function(params, options) {
  reqObj = createOptions(options);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    body = [];
    req = http.request(reqObj, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(body.join(''));
        resolve(body.join(''));
      });
    });
    req.on('error', function(err) {
      reject({ msg: "We're sorry, but something went wrong" });
    });
    if (params) { req.write(JSON.stringify(params)); }
    req.end();
  });
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I want to be sure it's clear: the only difference between the test passing and failing is if you change this line `.send({ email: 'realemail@gmail.com', password: 'RealPass'  })` to use real or fake email/password?

Comment: Hi Matt

Basically, yes.

Comment: If that is the case, then there is something amiss in your app, because there is nothing in the test code you provided that would cause that behavior.

Comment: Hi @MattR.Wilson

Sorry for the delay, but I updated the question, hope this helps to understand better the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: how are you starting your app for your tests? The "nocked" app and the tests are running in the same process, correct?

Comment: Yeah, using port 3000 for tests and development

Comment: I don't think the port is the issue. I'm questioning if the app and the tests are running in the same Nodejs process. Do you start the app, that listens on port 3000, somehow before kicking off the tests? Or is the Express app started in a file that Mocha runs before anything else?